# InvalidOperation Exception was unhandled

Tags: c#, devexpress

When inserting data to GridView shows this error:

> Rows cannot be programmatically added to the DataGridView's rows collection when the control is data-bound

[image: Untlited]

Comment: That's right, if your control is data bound you shoul change your data in data source, not trying to add something "manually"

Answer (score 0):

It's data bound. You'll have to change your data first, then call `DataBind()`.